# location directive getting ignored?

Tags: nginx

I need to deny all access to most files in a specific folder with Nginx

Here is my configuration that i tried.

```
location ~ /rapidleech/(classes|configs|files|hosts|languages|rar|templates) {
      deny  all;
    }

location /rapidleech/files/files.lst {
    allow all;
    }
```

Info : rapidleech folder contain classes(folder) , configs(folder) ....

Nginx seems to ignore the `allow all;` as i get 403 forbidden when trying to access

```
/rapidleech/files/files.lst
```

Any help is appreciated..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That because regexp location take precedence over normal location. Read [documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) about how nginx choose best matching location.

In your case you could prevent checking regexp location by using `^~` modifier:

```
location ~ /rapidleech/(classes|configs|files|hosts|languages|rar|templates) {
    deny  all;
}

location ^~ /rapidleech/files/files.lst {
    allow all;
}
```

Also, you should realize, that regexp locations match against any part of request, not only the beginning, so your configuration prevent access to `/some/path/rapidleech/classes` as well.

If it's possible to forbid all the `/rapidleech/` tree, it would be simpler and more efficient.

```
location /rapidleech/ {
    deny  all;
}

location /rapidleech/files/files.lst {
    allow all;
}
```